# Поменялся или изменился?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Что лучше использовать в данном предложении: "С 1 ноября **изменился** порядок регистрации новых пользователей." или "С 1 ноября **поменялся** порядок регистрации новых пользователей.".

И вообще, какая специфика использования каждого из этих слов и выражений с ними?

Answer (score 10):

Глагол *измениться* имеет значение *стать иным*. Поэтому верным будет выражение *порядок регистрации изменился*. Глагол поменяться имеет разговорный характер.