# "Поменялось" или "изменилось"? Оттенки значений слов с разными приставками

Tags: грамотная-речь, приставка

Скажите,  пожалуйста,  почему нельзя говорить :"Моё отношение к проблеме не поменялось"?  Это пример ошибки в "неразличии оттенков от наличия суффикса,  приставки".  Очень странно,  я бы так и сказала,  как неправильно

Comment: См. ответ на [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/25311/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F).

Comment: Если это не достаточно подробно, см. значение слова "поменять" [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: мое отношение к проблеме **не менялось/не изменилось.**

Глагол ***меняться*** в зависимости от его значения имеет разные видовые пары.

**МЕНЯТЬСЯ**,  нсв. 1. (св. обменяться и **поменяться**). кем-чем. Производить взаимный обмен. М. книгами. 2. (св. **обменяться**). чем. (с зависимым существительным). Обозначает взаимное действие, содержание которого раскрывает существительное.  М. репликами за столом. М. радостью. 3. (св. **смениться**). Замещать, сменять кого-л. В команде часто менялись тренеры. 4. (св. **измениться** и перемениться). **Становиться иным.**  **Меняется отношение к кому-л.**

Answer (score 2):

**Поменять** что-либо можно только *местами с чем-то другим* (например, переставив шкаф с диваном). Две сущности могут сами **поменяться местами** - с точки зрения наблюдателя (например, футбольные команды после игры в списке чемпионата). Можно **поменяться чем-либо с кем-либо**: поменяться *полками в купе, предметами коллекционирования* - это о двусторонней смене обладателей, *по договорённости*; в прочих контекстах глагол может не подойти (***об***меняться *взглядами, подарками, мнениями* - здесь имеет место ответное действие и не обязательно происходит "смена владельца"). В исходной фразе таких смыслов нет вообще: *отношение* остаётся самим собой на своём месте и только *оценивается по свойствам*, поэтому вместо "не поменялось" нужно сказать "**не изменилось**" .